# Excel VBA adding new row in table (excel crashing)

Tags: excel, vba

I have been building a workbook to store all my recipes, and I am trying to have inputs in a userform be added to the next row in a table from the recipeInfo object that contains all the data.

The Debug.print statements give the correct outputs as far as I can tell, but the lines below that are supposed to add the info into the row after the last one in the table causes excel to crash whenever I run it.

Am I doing something wrong with the recipeSheet.cells commands?

```
Sub addData(newRecipe As recipeInfo)

Dim col As Integer
Dim recipeSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set recipeSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Recipes")
lastRow = recipeSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'MsgBox (recipeSheet.Name & ", " & lastRow)

'add data into range

Debug.Print (newRecipe.item)
Debug.Print (newRecipe.cost)
Debug.Print (newRecipe.servings)
Debug.Print (newRecipe.cost / newRecipe.servings)
Debug.Print (newRecipe.ingredients)
Debug.Print (newRecipe.instructions)


recipeSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1) = newRecipe.item
recipeSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2) = newRecipe.cost
recipeSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3) = newRecipe.servings
recipeSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 4) = newRecipe.cost / newRecipe.servings
recipeSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 5) = newRecipe.ingredients
recipeSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 6) = newRecipe.instructions

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through (F8) to see if it's one particular line? Is there always a value in `newRecipe.servings`?

Comment: It quits at the first line (item), I also tried commenting out that line and the other lines make Excel quit as well. Also, all of the properties have values.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `recipeInfo` is a Class Module? If your code works on the `Debug.Print` lines and prints the correct output, I see no reason for the following lines to fail. If it fails on the first `Debug.Print` line, then you need to revisit your `Class Module` (again if my assumption is correct that it is such).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when you set the object list or table as a rowsource to a listbox you get this kind of error specially after you save the workbook and start adding again, check if you have in your project a listbox attached to that table and instead of making it on the proprieties of the listbox , code it when the userform initialize for me it worked that way I hope It helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Worksheets isn't protected, you can try to address the Cells().Value property of your cells instead of the Range objects as you do with .Cells().
Also, does Excel give you an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll want to use `.CurrentRegion` on a column that won't have blanks instead of `.UsedRange` to find the last row  of a dataset. `.UsedRange` tends to return all the cells you've scrolled to or assigned a format to rather than all the cells that have actual data.

This is probably resulting in `lastrow` being equal to the row of excels maximum row count. Then Excel crashes when it doesn't properly handle the error when you try to target a row beyond the max row.