# Write new row to table

Tags: excel, vba

I created a table in a Excel sheet (named Table1) with a header and a blank row. I can display it in a listBox on my form.
If I add a cell in the Excel table, I can display new cells when my script is running.

When I try to add a new cell with VBA, I have an error.

```vb
Dim MyTable as ListObject 
Dim newRow as ListRow

Set myTable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

nbLine = myTable.ListRows.Count

myTable.ListRows.Add
```

When I run this, nbLine writes the right number of lines of my table. But, when I run the `ListRows.Add`, I have the error

> 'Method 'Add' of object 'Listrows' failed'

and Excel crashes.

I tried `myTable.ListColumns.Add` and it works. It creates a column at the end of my table.

Why doesn't `ListRows.Add` work?

Also after creating a row, I want to add content to each column of my new row. I didn't find any command to do that. I found on the Microsoft documentation the property `DataBodyRange` but it only works in reading, not in writing.

How can I write to my table?

Comment: Have you tried it on a new workbook - the code works for me.

Comment: Hello, I tried on a new workbook and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I tried on a new workbook and it works fine. After renaming the new worksheet, it works. But after renaming the table, it didn't work. I then found that if I put an underscore '_' in the name of the table, the instruction listrows.add wont work. If I delete the underscore, the instruction works fine !
My problem appears because I put an underscore into my table's name.

After searching more similar subjects, I found this one: [Excel VBA adding new row in table (excel crashing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934624/excel-vba-adding-new-row-in-table-excel-crashing)

**The listrows.add wont work because the table is linked to a combobox. If you break the link in the form and create the link by code when launching the application, everything will work !**